# Quotient of abelian variety by finite group scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quotient-spaces, abelian-varieties, group-schemes

Let $X$ be an abelian variety over a field $k$. Let $G$ be a finite group scheme over $k$ acting on $X$ and denote $X/G$ to be the geometric quotient of $X$ by $G$, which always exists in this case. My question is this:

Is $X/G$ an abelian variety over $k$?

I understand that it is a group scheme of finite type over $k$.

Comment: Let $X$ be an elliptic curve and $G$ be $\mathbf Z/2 \mathbf Z$ acting by the hyperelliptic involution. Then $X/G$ is $\mathbf P^1$.

Comment: Okay thanks! Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: I don't know a reference offhand, but you can prove it yourself by computing the ring of invariants of $k[x,y]/(y^2-f(x))$ for $Z/2Z$ acting by $y \mapsto -y$.